# Pointers dereference to access array in another file

Tags: android, c, pointers, kernel

I keep on getting null pointer dereference and then kernel panic.
Can some one please tell me how to get around this.

file 1.c:

```
int get_data()
{
     int i;
     int *mv;
     unsigned long *f;

      if ((get_data_from_other_file(&mv, &f)) {
                 return error;
       }

      for ( i=0; mv[i]; i++)
                  printf("%d %lu", mv[i], f[i]);
}
```

file2.c:

```
struct data
{
   .mv = { 1,2,3,4,5 },
   .f = {4,5,5,3,2},
}datas;

int get_data_from_other_file(int **mv, unsigned long **f)
{
        *mv = datas.mv;
         *f = datas.f;

         for ( int i =0; datas.mv[i]; i++)
               printf ("%d %lu \n", *(mv[i]), *(f[i]));

           return 0;
}
```

I just want to be able to access the data from file2 in file1 without using malloc or new, or anything like that.

Comment: A *kernel panic*?  Where is this code being executed from?

Comment: this is inside kernel

Comment: i am trying to do something inside android kernel. Somehow i am not able to access malloc in this file. Tried using #include <stdlib.h> doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Here `printf ("%d %lu \n", *(mv[i]), *(f[i]));` you're dereferencing invalid addresses. 
`mv[i]` and `f[i]` are numbers that you've put in your `datas` structure (1,2,3,4,..). By applying `*` operator on them you're attempting to access memory at the specified address (1,2,3,4..). That's obviously wrong since these addresses aren't your's - they are reserved for system usage and contain important information which is protected.

It's not very clear what you're actually attempting to do but I don't see any reference to the file in your code.

Regading `malloc`: in kernel you should use `kmalloc` instead.

Comment: well the printk statement in the 2nd file was just to see if it is getting populated correctly. In the 1st file i missed to send double pointers in the function call. Removing the printk in the 2nd file fixes it.